# iPhone app system clock & sleep independent tick count

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to maintain a tick count in your iPhone app which is :

1. independent of system clock
2. is not impacted by device sleep (unlike CACurrentMediaTime(), UpTime() etc.)

Comment: could you give more info about why do you need it / how is it going to be used (i.e. is it for public audience, it's in house, should it support 3G and older, etc.)?

Comment: What do you mean by independent of system clock? Is `clock_t clock()` not good enough?

Comment: independent of system clock implies that the tickcount should not change if the user goes to the system clock and changes the time.

Comment: I wan't to block the user for some time if he enters the wrong password, but if I track system time the user can bypass the block by changing the time on the device, CACurrentMediaTime looks suitable for doing this but the only problem is that it does not tick when the deivce goes to sleep. Getting time from external sources is not an option since the user should be able to login even when no network is available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this class, it will access the Mach kernel time on the device (kind like tick count since system boot)
https://github.com/maddox/cocoaheads_gltouches/blob/master/Classes/MachTimer.m